# Does Go have no real way to shrink a slice? Is that an issue?

Tags: go, slice

I've been trying out Go for some time and this question keeps bugging me. Say I build up a somewhat large dataset in a slice (say, 10 million int64s).

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a []int64
    var i int64;
    upto := int64(math.Pow10(7))
    for i = 0; i < upto; i++ {
        a = append(a, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(cap(a))
}
```

But then I decide I don't want most of them so I want to end up with a slice of just 10 of those. I've tried both slicing and [delete techniques on Go's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks) but none of them seem to reduce the slice's capacity.

So that's my question: does Go has no real way of shrinking the capacity of a slice that would be similar to `realloc()`-ing with a smaller size argument than in your previous call on the same pointer in C? Is that an issue and how should one deal with it?

Comment: instead of `math.Pow10(7)` it's easier to just use `1e7`

Comment: To shrink the slice, the `slices.Clip` could do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459802/3011380

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To perform an, in effect, a realloc of a slice:

```
a = append([]T(nil), a[:newSize]...) // Thanks to @Dijkstra for pointing out the missing ellipsis.
```

If it does a copy of `newSize` elements to a new memory place or if it does an actual *in place* resize as in realloc(3) is at complete discretion of the compiler. You might want to investigate the current state and perhaps raise an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list) if there's a room for improvement in this.

However, this is likely a micro-optimization. The first source of performance enhancements lies almost always in selecting a better algorithm and/or a better data structure. Using a hugely sized vector to finally keep a few items only is probably not the best option wrt to memory consumption.

EDIT: The above is only partially correct. The compiler *cannot*, in the general case, derive if there are other pointers to the slice's backing array. Thus the realloc is not applicable. The above snippet is actually *guaranteed* to peform a copy of 'newSize' elements. Sorry for any confusion possibly created.

Comment: On my system when newSize is an odd number, the resulting capacity is newSize+1. When newSize is an even number, the resulting capacity is newSize.

Comment: @GonenI because allocations must always be a multiple of block size. The specified capacity is the minimum required and the actual capacity can be higher after rounding up

Answer (score 9):

Go does not have a way of shrinking slices. This isn't a problem in most cases, but if you profile your memory use and find you're using too much, you can do something about it:

Firstly, you can just create a slice of the size you need and copy your data into it. The garbage collector will then free the large slice. [Copy built-in](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

Secondly, you could re-use the big slice each time you wish to generate it, so you never allocate it more than once.

On a final note, you can use `1e7` instead of `math.Pow10(7)`.

Comment: To save people a click: the signature for `copy` is `copy(dst, src)`, not `copy(src, dst)`

Answer (score 5):

Let's see this example:

```
func main() {
    s := []string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"}
    fmt.Println(s, len(s), cap(s))  // slice, length, capacity

    t := s[2:4]
    fmt.Println(t, len(t), cap(t))

    u := make([]string, len(t))
    copy(u, t)
    fmt.Println(u, len(u), cap(u))
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
[A B C D E F G H] 8 8
[C D] 2 6
[C D] 2 2
```

`s` is a slice that holds 8 pieces of strings. `t` is a slice that keeps the part `[C D]`. The length of `t` is 2, but since it uses the same hidden array of `s`, its capacity is 6 (from "C" to "H"). The question is: how to have a slice of `[C D]` that is independent from the hidden array of `s`? Simply create a new slice of strings with length 2 (slice `u`) and copy the content of `t` to `u`. `u`'s underlying hidden array is different from the hidden array of `s`.

The initial problem was this: you have a big slice and you create a new smaller slice on it. Since the smaller slice uses the same hidden array, the garbage collector won't delete the hidden array.

See the bottom of this post for more info: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals .

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you can re-use most of the allocated memory during work of yours app, take a look at: [bufs package](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/bufs)

PS if you re-alocate new memory for smaller slice, old memory *may not* be freed in same time, it will be freed when garbage collector decides to.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature called 3-index slice in Go 1.2, which means to get part of a slice in this way:

```golang
slice[a:b:c]
```

In which the `len` for the returned slice whould be `b-a`, and the `cap` for the new slice would be `c-a`.

Tips: no copy is down in the whole process, it only returns a new slice which points to `&slice[a]` and has the len as `b-a` and cav as `c-a`.

And that's the only thing you have to do:

```
slice= slice[0:len(slice):len(slice)];
```

Then the `cap` of the slice would be changed to `len(slice) - 0`, which is the same as the `len` of it, and no copy is done.

Comment: Nice way, but hard to comprehend. A playground example would be really helpful

Comment: @SamirKape playground https://go.dev/play/p/nInKckZ50BY

Comment: Does `cav` actually mean something or should it be `cap`?

Comment: @unifreak yeah, it should be ```cap```, changed it. My fault, XD

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by re-assigning the slice's value to a portion of itself

```
  a := []int{1,2,3}
  fmt.Println(len(a), a) // 3 [1 2 3]

  a = a[:len(a)-1]
  fmt.Println(len(a), a) //2 [1 2]
```

Comment: That does not change the capacity of the slice, which is what the OP was looking for. Even then, the OP was looking for a way to relinquish the memory no longer used by the populated portion of the slice.