# How do I manually reserve space for an existing slice in Go?

Tags: go

I’m appending the values of a map into an ***existing*** slice.

The code’s like (the `s` is a slice that already has some elements in it):

```golang
for key, value := range m {
    s = append(s, value)
}
```

As far as I know, slices in Go double their sizes when needed. I could let it double the capacity of itself, but it’ll happen several times a loop, which probably is bad for performance.

In this case, I know the exact space needed, that is, `len(m)`. How do I “reserve” the space for a slice, like that in C++? I want the reallocation to happen just once.

Comment: did you read through https://blog.golang.org/slices? it explains some approaches

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Go have no real way to shrink a slice? Is that an issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748330/does-go-have-no-real-way-to-shrink-a-slice-is-that-an-issue)

Comment: Create a new slice with enough size to hold values from the old slice + the inserted ones, then `copy` all of it over. This would guarantee only 1 reallocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocate memory for an object with [`make`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make), like ([play](https://play.golang.org/p/8f145OlpT8z)):

```
s := make([]string, len(m))
for i, v := range m {
    s[i] = v
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a slice of length zero, but with enough capacity to hold n values. Here, append will never need to be allocate new memory, if the number of items appended does not exceed capacity ([play](https://play.golang.org/p/-zmMc_4zaPH)).

```
s := make([]string, 0, len(m))
for _, v := range m {
    s = append(s, v)
}
```

If you like to dive into slices more visually, this blog post may help:

- https://divan.dev/posts/avoid_gotchas/#arrays-and-slices

If you want to manually enlarge an slices with element you would need to:

- create a new slice of desired capacity (and length)
- use [`copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) to copy elements over

Example on [play](https://play.golang.org/p/tK-71BmqLnE).

Comment: I already have a slice that has some elements in it. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @КонстантинВан, updated my answer - you'll need to allocate, then copy - similar to what append would do internally, but manually with the capacity of your choice.

Comment: @КонстантинВан, I added play links to the examples, e.g. for copy here: https://play.golang.org/p/tK-71BmqLnE